# JS function parameters + Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have Object with 2 parameters - Obj3D, Name and
I want to load object by name:

```
function load3DObjectByName(obj, loader)
{
    loader.load(
        "resources/3D/meshes.dae",
        function(collada) {
            obj.Obj = collada.scene.getChildByName(obj.Name, true);
            window.alert(obj.Obj["name"]); // obj.Obj != undefined
    }
    );
     window.alert(obj.Obj["name"]); // obj.Obj == undefined
}
```

But obj.Obj is sill undefined after loading... loader = ColladaLoader.

Comment: Looks like `load` is asynchronous, is it?

Comment: if i check obj.Obj in function(collada){} - is loaded there, but outside (in load3DObjectByName function ) is still empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `loader.load` is asynchronous then don't expect to have the object being populated straight away after the function call. In other words:

```
load3DObjectByName(obj, loader);
//obj might not be ready yet.
```

Use a promise instead or keep on using CPS.

```
function load3DObjectByName(obj, loader)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        loader.load(
            "resources/3D/meshes.dae",
            function(collada) {
                obj.Obj = collada.scene.getChildByName(obj.Name, true);
                resolve(obj);
            }
        );
    });
}

var prom = load3DObjectByName(obj, loader);
prom.then(function(obj){
    //obj here is finished and can be used now.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As MinusFour pointed out, loader.load is asynchronous. What that means is - the code is getting executed as

```
loader.load(..., youranonymousfunctionReference)
window.alert(...
// and then from eventloop
youranonymousfunctionReference.
```

so when window.alert is called the anonymous function has not been executed and hence Obj is undefined.